# Json.Net проверка на пустоту

Tags: c#

Собственно, для работаю с Json для обработки использую Json.Net.

При проверки на пустоту не существующих json элементов(так надо) вылезает ошибка "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект".
  Как можно её избежать?

Comment: Попробуйте установить `[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]`. Или покопайтесь в [`SerializationSettings`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationSettings.htm), там наверняка найдётся что-то.

Comment: Обернул в try и catch и фиг с ним